# What will browser show when a user access website and website present certificate of some other domain with same top level domain

Tags: tls, openssl, certificates, certificateless-crypto

For example, User tries to access a.example.com and server presents abc.example.com with a.example.com not in SANs list.
Will it be just a warning or an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A well designed browser should display a warning page whenever there is a problem with a certificate for the asked paged.

Firefox and Chrome will provide a way to manually bypass the page.